# iPhone 6 Plus auto hides the status bar in landscape mode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8, xcode6, iphone-6-plus

My current application supports only landscape mode. I'm presenting the menu when the user hits the bar button item on the top part right under the status bar.
Recently, I checked my application in iPhone 6 Plus simulator, status bar is not shown in my application as it supports only landscape mode.
In landscape mode, my menu is hanging on the left side of the device instead of sticking to the top.
Is this happening because of the status bar missing ?
I want to show the status bar in the application as well as fix the menu hanging on the left side.
Help me out!

Answer (score 3):

I added the following lines in the ViewWillAppear method which fixed the Status bar missing issue.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

Answer (score 2):

Compiling with the Xcode 6 SDK appears to hide the status bar by default on iPhone landscape.

You can get the status bar back by setting `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES` in your `Info.plist` and then adding the following code to your `UIViewController`:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Hey, Your solution partially works, now the status bar's position is not occupied by the navigation bar. But the status bar contents are still not showing up!! Why ?? here is the result. http://d.pr/i/8df7/5R1pGxP3

Comment: At the time of app launch it launches with blank status bar, When its rotated to landscape left or landscape right it shows the status bar contents automatically.